# How to display position in Python code after stopping by sys.exit() in Spyder 5

Tags: spyder

To interrupt the code at defined positions I place in the code the command `sys.exit()`.

The program stops but does not return the stopping position. Neither in the console nor in the code window I see at which point the program has stopped. As I have several stop commands I do not know where the program has exited and I become completely lost in the code.

Is this a bug? How can I stop programmatically a code with output of the position? What is the fastest way?

I use Spyder 5.1.5 and Spyder 5.2 with WinPython 3.9.5.0 and the programs are used without installation on Win10Pro version 21H1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys.exit()` without any parameter just terminates the execution without any further information.

If you need to see witch `sys.exit` line was called you have several options. Here are 2 simple solutions for that.

1°) The simple way

`sys.exit()` accept a parameter. When you pass a string, this string will be printed on exit. You can take advantage of this to trace witch exit point was used.

Example:

```
if True:
  sys.exit("exit point 1")
else:
  sys.exit("exit point 2")
```

will print the folling when executed:

```
exit point 1
```

This is very straighforward but needs to make a full pass on your code to change all `sys.exit` calls. Luckily there is a less intrusive option.

2°) Using `SystemExit` exception

`sys.exit()`, ultimatly raises a `SystemExit` exception. As every other exception it can be catched, so you can then print the call stack using the `traceback` module.

All you have to do is surrounding you main program with a `try:` `except SystemExit:` to intercept the `sys.exit()` call and print the call stack.

Here is a simple example :
import sys
import traceback

```
def test():
  print ("entering test")
  sys.exit()
  print ("leaving test")

try:
  test()
  sys.exit()
except SystemExit as e:
  traceback.print_exc()
  raise e
```

The output of this program will be:

```
entering test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    test()
  File "test.py", line 6, in test
    sys.exit()
  SystemExit
```

So you can see you exited through the line 6 of file test.py

The behavior is well documented on the python standard library documentation :
https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html (chapter sys.exit)

Comment: It seems for me like a bug that you have to correct this by yourself. Actually I want to know how to stop the code at defined position with output of the position, not necessarily using sys.exit(). Without this function a programming IDE is useless. For example in IDL language you place any nonsense characters (you just write 'ss' or some other unknown command) in a line and the program stops with output of position. This is a fast method.  Writing sys.exit("exit point 1") is very cumbersome.